# BigQuery Firebase Crashlytics - Reloading data

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics

Recently I started playing with BigQuery and my firebase crashlytics data. At some point this morning, I needed to refresh the data but I couldn't change the TTL so I deleted the dataset and disabled/reenabled the BigQuery integration thinking it would just create a new dataset and repopulate the tables with more up to date data.

I also found out today that this didn't work and now my dataset for crashlytics is coming back as 0 bytes (no data).

Any recommendations on where to go from here? I'm a little surprised there isn't a "refresh data or reload data" on either Firebase or BigQuery where I can just re-populate a dataset with a given set of params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out

Go to transfers in the bigQuery page and create a new transfer.

On the create new transfer screen, select the crashlytics as the source, give it a display name, and make the destination asset be your crashlytics dataset. then click add.

After you click add, click schedule backfill, put in your date range and press ok.

This should go and add your data in to your datasets!!

Comment: Do you even need to create a new transfer? I just used the already existing "Firebase Crashlytics Export" to schedule the backfill.